# code is showing error in IPython console. But run fine and correctly in window command prompt. can anyone explain why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

code is showing error in IPython console ( console window)  as TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. But run fine and correctly in window command prompt. can anyone explain why?
#parse xml data _from_url_source

## check with url: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

xml_url = input('enter url :')
xml_read= urllib.request.urlopen(xml_url).read()
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_read)

lst =tree.findall('comments/comment')
sum_count =0
for item in lst:
    print('name:',item.find('name').text)
    print('count:',item.find('count').text)
    x = item.find('count').text
    sum_count =sum_count+ int(x)
print(sum_count)
```

Comment: Don't execute `input = ...` or `int = ...` before running your code (or ever, actually)

Comment: Which line of code is it complaining about?